# How to generate a Auto Increment column for a XML query?

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath

Let's say you have an XML input that looks like this:

```
<fusionlist>
    <fusion>
       <page number="2" sourcedocumentid="5"></page>
       <page number="3" sourcedocumentid="6"></page>
    </fusion>
    <fusion>
       <page number="1" sourcedocumentid="5"></page>
    </fusion>
</fusionlist>
```

As you can see, fusion is a group of values that has no unique identifier, and it makes it hard to manage it with classic SQL (let's say you want to iterate these groups.

And you want to extract values to an Sql Table (with TSQL), so your output would be like:

```
FusionTable
FusionGroupId | PageNumber | SourceDocumentId
1               2            5
1               3            6    
2               1            5
```

What would be the best option to generate the FusionGroupId column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query the group where you want to calculate your autogenerated column to be, in this case it would be **'fusionlist/fusion'**.

Then select a **ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n.d)** to get that value, and make available the current node with the query  ('.').

After that, standard **.value()** calls can be used to extract the desired data.

```
SELECT 
    t.RowNumber,
    fusion.value('(@sourcedocumentid)[1]','bigint') AS SourceDocumentId,
    fusion.value('(@number)[1]','tinyint') AS PageNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n.d) AS RowNumber,
        n.d.query('.') query
    FROM
     @FusionSourceXml.nodes('fusionlist/fusion') n(d)
 )t
    CROSS APPLY 
      t.query.nodes('fusion/page') AS x(fusion)
```

Would produce:

```
1   5   2
1   6   3
2   5   1
```